# How to align two lines at some specific place

Tags: html

In html, I try to make my address look like:

Address: 123 Apple Street
                Cherry City

I.e., I want the "1" in the first line aligning with the "C" in the second line. I am wondering besides the silly code as

```
<p>Address: 123 Apple Street<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cherry City</p>
```

what else could I do?

Comment: A table, inline blocks, absolute positioning, relative positioning, flex boxes, take your pick.

Comment: I looked into the table. While either ```Address: <table>
  <tr>
  <td>123 Apple Street</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cherry City</td>
  </tr>
</table>``` or ```<table>
  <tr>
  Address:  <td>123 Apple Street</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cherry City</td>
  </tr>
</table>```, the "Address:" and "123 Apple Street" go into separate lines. Is there a way to put them in the same line?

Comment: See my answer for examples for all of these methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table or inline blocks are probably the easiest and cleanest solutions, but I've included the others as well for completeness.

### Table:

```css
td
{
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Address:</td>
    <td>123 Apple St</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cherry City</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### Inline Blocks:

```css
div
{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>Address:</div>
<div>
  123 Apple St<br>
  Cherry City
</div>
```

### Absolute Positioning:

```css
div.position
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div>Address:</div>
<div class="position">123 Apple St<br>Cherry City</div>
```

### Relative Positioning:

```css
span
{
  position: relative;
  left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Address: 123 Apple St<br>
  <span>Cherry City</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `padding-left` and `text-indent`

*Sample*

```css
p {
  padding-left: 3.9em;
  text-indent: -3.9em;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Address: 123 Apple Street<br />
  Cherry City
</p>
```